# No logro ver el error

Tags: reactjs

Bueno empecé mi segundo proyecto recién y a diferencia del primero, no me ha cargado a la izquierda la carpeta de SRC.
Y el error que me marca no lo entiendo. ¿Tiene que ver con Node?
Soy Junior, por cierto, por eso hay cosas con las que aún[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] no me familiarizo.

Comment: arrastra y suelta la carpeta con la que trabajas en el editor, en la consola dirígete hasta tu carpeta y ejecuta el comando `npm init` esto inicializa un proyecto de node

Comment: Binevenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Evita usar imagenes de tu código o mensajes de error, aunque comprendo que para este caso tal vez la imagen muestra claramente que no estás ejecutando VSCode desde la carpeta o directorio donde tienes tu solución (aplicación). Saludos

Comment: por lo que se entiende de tu pregunta, estas intentando correr un script "npm start" donde ni siquiera hay un archivo "package.json", si estas empezando con react, yo te recomeindo que visites [esta](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) pagina para que puedas iniciar tus proyectos de react sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo aún no has hecho la instalación de React o no tienes ningún package.json en la carpeta que estás posicionado.

Si lo que quieres es iniciar un proyecto de Reactjs, escribe:

npx create-react-app NOMBREDETUAPP

En caso de que sólo quieras correr node, no tienes un package.json activo, escribe entonces
npm init
esto creará el paquete que necesitas, sin embargo, si lo que quieres es comenzar en React, no empieces por esto y mejor aplica el primer comando.